# Dockerize Nodejs Python Project (Using Dockerfile)

Tags: python, node.js, docker, npm, streamlit

I am currently working for bachelor thesis on a web app together with [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/).
However, I want to use a vue template [from this github](https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-component-template-vue) repository over here.
For this, I need to install **Nodejs**, **Python** and using **npm or yarn** the needed packages inside the github repository. I want to dockerize everything in one container.

*original setup needs this commands including **Python 3.6+, Node.js**, and **npm***

1. py3 env & streamlit package

```
$ python3 -m venv venv  # create venv

$ . venv/bin/activate   # activate venv

$ pip install streamlit # install streamlit
```

2. npm install modules of project

```
$ cd my_component/frontend

$ npm install    # Install npm dependencies

$ npm run serve  # Start the Webpack dev server
```

3. 

```
$ . venv/bin/activate  # activate the venv you created earlier

$ streamlit run my_component/__init__.py  # run the example
```

I tried to setup everything with this dockerfile content:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV TZ=Europe
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

EXPOSE 8501
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN apt update -y  && \
    apt install -y git && \
    apt install -y curl  && \
    apt install -y python3-pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash  && \
    apt install -y nodejs  && \
    node -v  && \
    npm -v  && \
    git clone https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-component-template-vue && \
    cd streamlit-component-template-vue/my_component/frontend && \
    rm -rf node_modules && \
    export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && \
    npm i && \
    npm run build && \  
    ls -a
CMD streamlit run streamlit-component-template-vue/my_component/__init__.py
```

But at the point "yarn build" (or yarn run serve) I receive module errors like 
*TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'onMounted'.* 
 (Check the Screenshot)

What did I do wrong? Without docker, on my local machine, everything works as anticipated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am most certain the issue is caused by the line:

```
 rm -rf package-lock.json &&
```

Remove that and rebuild your image.

The lock file will help keep node_modules the project relies upon at their desired versions (I.e it helps keep identical trees of dependencies everywhere)

Comment: This worked indeed! Thanks (switched back 2 npm)